# Emoji's cause Express server to crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, emoji

I am trying to create a POST with an emoji to my Express endpoint:

```
curl --data '{"x": 10, "y":10, "z":10, "message": "", "userToken": "Marine"}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:3000/api/messages
```

For some reason this crashes my server:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    at Object.parse (native)
    at parse (/Users/user/Documents/uncovery/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:84:17)
    at /Users/user/Documents/uncovery/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:102:18
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/user/Documents/uncovery/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:149:7)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I went to my router and put console.log's in my `/messages` endpoint to see what is being received but when Express crashes as a result of sending an emoji the `console.log` is never activated.

**router.js**

```
var models = require('../db/models.js');
var util = require('../core/utilities.js');
var sockets = require('../routes/sockets.js');

module.exports = function(router) {
  //input: {x: float, y: float, z: float, message: string, userToken: string}
  router.post('/messages', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Emoji: ", req.body);
    models.createMessage(req.body).then(
      util.resolvePOST.bind(this, req, res),
      util.rejectPOST.bind(this, req, res)
      );
  });
}
```

I suspect this has something to do with the middleware and not actually related to the routes, but when I google [emojis crash node js](https://www.google.com/search?q=emojis&oq=emo&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j69i60j0.1163j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=emojis%20crash%20express%20js) I can't find anything relevant. Why is this happening?

**index.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var express = require('express');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var util = require('./server/core/utilities.js');
var router = require('./server/routes/router.js');
var sockets = require('./server/routes/sockets.js');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);

app.use(morgan('combined', util.getLogStream()));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use('/api', router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server/landing'));

var io = socketIO(server);
sockets.initialize(io);

server.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Uncovery listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Looks like it's nodejs crashes on `JSON.parse`. What version do you run? Couldn't reproduce on v0.10.37 with http://pastebin.com/SbWKWymU

Comment: Hey there,
I am running node v0.12.2, Express 4.12.3, and bodyParser 1.12.3

Comment: So could you reproduce it using the same script I shown?

Comment: JSON.parse does work. However, it is bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }) which does not work. I am not sure how to use JSON.parse instead of bodyParser.json because I am not very familiar with Express middleware architecture.